# Shield Upgrade needs a System Upgrade

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When I first upgrade my shielding to 3 bars, I tried powering it up. However it says "Requires System Upgrade". What system upgrade do I need to power this up? I have enough reactor energy so I'm not sure what I need. Do I have to buy it from a merchant?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need 2 shield upgrades for another point in shields, so if you have an uneven number of shield upgrades you need to add one more to actually make use of it.

2 points in shields => 1 shield
4 points in shields => 2 shields
...

Comment: Ah right, now I see that. I should probably pay more attention =P

Comment: Although if you're a bit low on scrap, don't hesitate to upgrade one at a time, that extra (unpowered) bar can provide a bit of a buffer against minor system damage.